# Commands in CMD prompt are not regognized

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I am making attempts to code... :) Hence I recently installed anaconda and thru Jupiter notebook began to make some python exercises. Today I decided to go back to the basics and practice some stuff in CMD Prompt (windows 8.1). Unfortunately many commends previously successfully ran gave me the result of "...is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file". Commands such as pwd, cd~.
Did I mess up the variables of OS? 
Knowing little (way too little) I uninstalled Anaconda... to no avail.
Could anybody, please provide me with any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Those are Unix shell commands, not for CMD.

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

> Unfortunately, many commands that ran successfully previously gave me the result of `... is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file`.

The commands you seem to be having issues with are all variations on *Nix-specific shell commands, which aren't normally available on Windows.

There are some native "cross-over" commands (e.g. `cd` without the special "home" directory syntax of `~`), but other commands just aren't usable (e.g. `pwd`).

**Recommendation**

The way to (mostly) overcome this is to install Windows ports of these commands/utilities. One such project is [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) but other similar projects exist as well. Based on your command examples, I would recommend downloading the individual [GNUWin32 CoreUtils package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

After installation, add your GNUWIn32 `bin` directory to your Windows Path to use the included utilites from the command line. You should then have e.g. `pwd` and a number of other similar basic commands available. If you need more utilities, you can then download those additional packages as well.

---

*Please note that this recommendation intentionally skips over things such as the (relatively) recent Windows Subsystem for Linux, Cygwin, Git For Windows, etc.*

---

---

**GNUWin32 Notes**

*GNUWin32 Advantages*

- The project ports a large amount of utilities, especially in comparison to some other similar projects.
- GNUWin32 ports work directly at the command line without a special "interface" (this isn't always true of other implementations). These ports can be placed in an installation directory and added to your path like any normal program (as above).
- GNUWin32 has a "bulk" installer for all 400+ ports (several hundred MBs) if you want everything they have to offer or you can install packages individually (as above).

*GNUWin32 Caveats*

- Some ported utilities may not have the exact same features as their original *Nix counterparts. This is due to the fundamental differences between Windows and *Nix-style operating systems.
- Not all utilities may work perfectly. This can sometimes be due to bugs or again, underlying, fundamental differences between Windows and *Nix-style OSes. Anecdotally, however, these issues aren't likely to be widespread or serious.
- Not all command forms/syntax are supported. For instance, `cd~` still won't work and e.g. the GNUWin32 version of `find` may have stricter requirements on the arguments/forms you can use on Windows. But again, anecdotally, this doesn't seem to be widespread nor does it seriously interfere with most normal usage.
- Naming conflicts can occur. One example is `sort`. There's already a Windows `sort` utility which has a different set of features than the GNUWin32 port of `sort`. This can be overcome through renaming the given GNUWin32 `.exe`, but it is something to be aware of since there are potentially a number of duplicated command names. You can use `where some-command` to see the location(s) of a command/utility in Windows. The first entry returned is what will be called at the command line.
- GNUWin32 may not provide the most up-to-date ports of a given utility. If you can find other ports, you may wish to consider using those.
- Note that the installer that downloads all the packages at once also sometimes has more updated versions of a given utility than a corresponding individual package link.

Comment: A)cygwin is definitely much more up to date than gnuwin32 B)The commands Git adds are just using minggw.